# Disallow empty content in a BBCode tag with an attribute

Tags: regex, pcre

I have this regex:

```
\[code(?:=(["']?)(.{0,50}?)\1)?\](?!\s*\[\/code\])(.*?)\[\/code\]
```

This regex is supposed to support:

```
[code]content[/code]
[code=Title]content[/code]
[code="Title"]content[/code]
[code='Title']content[/code]
```

Empty contents `[code][/code]` are not allowed and this is done thanks to:

```
(?!\s*\[\/code\])
```

Also empty contents with title `[code=Title][/code]` are not allowed, and the above non-capturing group is working also for that condition, until I do not insert two tags together:

```
[code="title"][/code]
[code][/code]
```

How can I not make match the last condition by the regex?
The problem can best be observed here: https://regex101.com/r/J1dwJa/2/

As I understand, what it is creating problems is this part of the regex:

```
(["']?)
```

I am using the quantifier in order to support the pattern `[code=Title][/code]`. What this regex needs, at least I think, is that when it encounters `]` should stop and do not go on. I am trying but I am not finding any path with my basic regex knowledge.

Comment: you want something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/J1dwJa/3/) ?

Comment: Just remove the `singleline flag ( s )` and you're good to go

Comment: @CodeManiac I know, but I want the `s` flag included since it is a BBCode and needs to be flexible on new lines.

Comment: So you realize in your selected answer that `[^\]\[]*` in a quote body prohibits braces between quotes ? You've spent so much regex energy getting the proper open and close quote, yet you don't allow the only characters `[]` the quotes are used for ? Pretty odd and you've thrown out the baby with the bathwater. You've sunk the ship to get rid of the mice, etc ... The equivalent is in HTML attrib/value quoting. They protect `<>`  like marks if not in their entity form (which is possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should care about two things:

1. `.` would match much more than needed
2. You shouldn't match a `[/code]` in content part while looking for the closing `[/code]`

```
\[code(?>=(["']?)([^][]*)\1)?](?:(?!\s*(\[\/code])).)+(?3)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/BcqmmO/4)

Comment: You got it with the first point, thanks! While for the second point, I did not understand  what you mean. With the negative lookahead `(?!\s*\[\/code\])` I am specifying that every type of space (typing only spaces) is disallowed. In fact implementing your first point, the regex is working correctly: https://regex101.com/r/J1dwJa/6. Instead on yours, plain spaces are matched: https://regex101.com/r/BcqmmO/2

Comment: Your regex matches the first `[/code]` that engine needs but  it's possible that engine will match other occurrences of `[/code]` before matching the right `[\code]`. With `(?:(?!(\[\/code])).)+` I'm telling engine that never pass a `[/code]` before matching the right `[/code]`. Also adding `\s*` right before `\[\/code]`, as you did yourself, will reject whitespace-only bodies too.

Answer (score 1):

Regex engines will not give up on a match until it has tried all possibilities.
In your regex, this sequence `.{0,50}?` will match non-greedily, from 0 to 50 characters.

In your regex101 sample, you've specified the Dot-all modifier //s which means
 your dot there will span lines.
 It just so happens that on the next line it can satisfy a body (content) where
(?! \s* [/code] ) passes.

You'll notice that for this to happen, the quote is given up on a backtrakck,
 so that `( ["']? )` never gets matched and the `\1` is just an empty string.
 This leaves the door open for the non-greedy sequence to turn greedy.
 This is a GOTCHA moment.

***Update***

After further review, I firmly believe there is only 1 way
to satisfy all conditions to make this a viable regex.
The steps are:

1. ***Wrap the quote part around an atomic group.***
   This makes this part of the match impervious to backtracking.
2. ***Use an alternation to distinguish between a quoted value or non-quoted.***
   Put the quoted part first.
   *Note that you can't use a negative class inside the quoted part at all (i.e. `[^\[\]]` ) since the idea of a quote is to allow delimiters like `[]`.

   This part has to passively allow any character `.`.

   This will allow the matching of a string like this

   `[code="t][/code]"]hello world[/code]`

   however implausible generating such a string may be*.

And that's it. If it's done any other way it's just plain wrong.
I include a link that shows all the possible cases.
If you find an error... ah, there is none.

Group 2 and 3 contain the values (one or the other), just join
them.
Group 4 contains the content.

```
(?s)\[code(?>(?:=(?:(["'])(.{0,50}?)\1|([^\]]{0,50})))?)\](?!\s*\[\/code\])(.*?)\[\/code\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/cO73iA/1

Explained

```
 (?s)                      # Dot-all modifier
 \[code                    # Open bbcode tag
 (?>                       # Atomic group, can't be backtracked into
      (?:
           =
           (?:
                ( ["'] )                  # (1), Quote
                ( .{0,50}? )              # (2), code value
                \1                        # Backref to Quote
             |                          # or,
                ( [^\]]{0,50} )           # (3), Un-quoted code value
           )
      )?
 )
 \]
 (?! \s* \[/code\] )       # Cannot be empty content
 ( .*? )                   # (4), Content, must be some
 \[/code\]                 # Close bbcode tag
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following updated regex

```
\[code(?:=(["']?)([^'"]{0,50}?)\1)?\](?!\s*\[\/code\])(.*?)\[\/code\]
```

instead of use `.{0,50}` use `[^'"]{0,50}` that match any char except `"` or `'`

check its matches in the following [link](https://regex101.com/r/J1dwJa/5)

Comment: It is working but I prefer to have included `'"` in the title attribute, so if someone want to insert this chars can do that, it is more flexible. What this regex needs is that when it encounters "\]" should stop and do not go on. I am trying but I am not finding any path with my basic regex knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression works fine, we might just want to remove the `s` flag, if we wish to these instance in the original demo:

```
[code='title'][/code]
[code="title"][/code]
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/C3NXzM/1/)

We might also be able to a bit simplify our expression to:

```
\[code(?:=(["']?)(.{0,50}?)\1)?\](.+?)\[\/code\]
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9kPMql/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I already said in the comments, I need the `s` flag because it is a BBCode, it needs to match new lines.